# Table not building

Tags: tablesorter

So as I'm not knowledgeable about jQuery and JavaScript I'm following the simpler method of using an array to build a table with Tablesorter. However, this is not working at all. In fact, even if I use the example provided (here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html) there is no result just a blank webpage. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing Tablesorter (fork)</title>
        <!-- load tableSorter theme -->
        <link href="./includes/tablesorter-master/css/theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- load jQuery and tableSorter scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <!-- load tableSorter widgets -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                // Call the PHP script that grabs all data from DB
                $.getJSON('./get_data.php',function(data){
                    //alert(data.length);
                    var dataArr = new Array();
                    for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
                    {
                        dataArr[x] = data[x];
                        //console.log(dataArr[$x]);
                    }
                    applyTable(dataArr);              
                });
            });

            function applyTable(arrayIn)
            {
                //alert(arrayIn[0]);
                $('#topdiv').tablesorter({
                    theme : 'default',
                    //widgets : ['zebra','columns'],
                    debug : true,
                    widgetOptions : { 
                        build_source : arrayIn, 
                        build_headers : { 
                            rows : 1, 
                            classes : [], 
                            text : [],
                            widths  : [ '15%', '15%', '30%', '15%', '40%', '30%', '30%', '30%', '30%', '30%' ] 
                        } 
                    }
                });
                $("#topdiv").trigger("updateAll");
            }
        </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="topdiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Mottie, where are you.

<strike>**EDIT:** Chrome reports no JavsScript errors. Though the console (since I specified "debug: true") gives:</strike>

`stopping initialization! No table, thead, tbody or tablesorter has already been initialized`

I also know that the PHP script is working fine.

**EDIT, PHP CODE (excerpt):**

```
$headersArr = array('ID', 'Col 2', 'Col 3',
                    'Col 4', 'Col 5', 'Col 6',
                    'Col 7', 'Col 8', 'Col 9', 'Col 10');

$allArr = array();
array_push($allArr, $headersArr);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
    $newRow = array($row->id, $row->col_B, $row->col_C, 
                    $row->col_D, $row->col_E, 
                    $row->col_F, $row->col_G,
                    $row->col_H, $row->col_I,
                    $row->col_J);
    array_push($allArr, $newRow);
}
echo json_encode($jobsArr);
```

The following image is the JavaScript output in the Chrome console (I have not updated the code above to keep it from getting to big, but I simply repacked the array passed to `applyTable()` and outputted both arrays to the console). Which one of these arrays should be for use with Tablesorter?

[image: Array of arrays, or array of an array of arrays?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table was not building due to missing the line in the HTML header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-build-table.js"></script>
```

The PHP script is absolutely fine. The only JavaScript req'd is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('./get_data.php',function(data){
                    applyTable(data);            
                });
            });

            function applyTable(arrayIn){
                $('#topdiv').tablesorter({
                    theme: 'default',
                    //widgets : ['zebra','columns'],
                    debug: true,
                    widgetOptions: { 
                        build_source: arrayIn, 
                        build_headers: { 
                            rows: 1
                        } 
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, it looks like the array is just one long array.

```
dataArr = [ 'r0c0', 'r0c1', 'r0c2', 'r1c0', 'r1c1', 'r1c2', ... ];
```

It needs to be an array of row arrays:

```
dataArr = [ 
    ['r0c0', 'r0c1', 'r0c2'],
    ['r1c0', 'r1c1', 'r1c2'],
    ...
];
```

so make two loops ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2184/)):

```
$(function () {
    // Declare the array holding the data
    var dataArr = [];
    // Call the PHP script that grabs all data from DB
    $.getJSON('./get_data.php', function (data) {
        var i, j, row,
        // you need to know how many columns
        columns = 3,
        // calculate how many rows
        rows = Math.ceil(data.length / columns);

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            // clear row array
            row = [];
            for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                row.push(data[i * columns + j]);
            }
            dataArr.push(row);
        }
        applyTable(dataArr);
    });

});

function applyTable(arrayIn) {
    $('#topdiv').tablesorter({
        theme: 'default',
        //widgets : ['zebra','columns'],
        widgetOptions: {
            build_source: arrayIn,
            build_headers: {
                rows: 1,
                widths: ['33%', '33%', '33%']
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And don't trigger an "updateAll" because the table was just built.

The error you mentioned is still showing up, it looks like an bug, but it's just an unintentional message, nothing else.

Comment: Mottie, my PHP script doesn't return a continuous array. Please see an excerpt of the code above.

Comment: Can you modify the above demo with a sample of your data and make sure it works; I mean that demo works, so I can only guess that the problem is in the data array.

Comment: I will go ahead and do this and report back shortly. However, you have said and shown through your example that this takes an array of arrays right (?). Well, the PHP script above that you are able to see is correct isn't it? And which of the two arrays logged to Chrome console shown above in the image would you expect to work as the array to feed Tablesorter?

Comment: I would guess the top array, but Chrome collapses the output so you can't tell if there are nested arrays without exapanding it and looking.

Comment: Right, but the programming I'm using is all above. I don't see why further nested arrays could be a potential issue/bug because that's not programmed in either the PHP or JavaScript. It's just one array element from `data` (which as you can see in the PHP is an array of arrays) pushed to the next position of the array `dataArr` in a loop of length `data.length` before being passed to the applyTable() function. What gives. Apologies for any frustrations caused; I am a novice...

Comment: Mottie, I re-wrote the above code. This time I completely unpacked the JSON `data` into one continuous array to mirror your use of a continuous array. From there I used your code. There was still no table. Looking at your JSFiddle I could see that you had included the widget `widget-build-table.js` so I linked this in and voila. So the widget solved it. I think I will go back now and see if my original code was working before unpacking `data`.

Comment: I'll update the build widget docs to include the scripts/css required in the `<head>`. I'm glad it's working now! whew!